# How to append column values of one dataframe to column of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with 2 dataframes, A & B. Dataframe A is populated with values, while dataframe B is empty except for a header structure
I want to take the value of column in dataframe A, and append them to the corresponding column in dataframe B.

I've placed the values of the dataframe A column I want to append in a list. I 've tried setting the destination column values to equal the list of start column values, but that gives me the following error:

```
dataframeB[x] = list(dataframeA[A])
```

This yields the following error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

The result I expect is 
Dataframe A's column A transfers over to Dataframe B's column x

```
  A  B  C  D  
  1  2  3  4  
  1  2  3  4
```

Dataframe B

```
  x  y 
  -  -
```

Comment: you mean `df2.x=df1.A`? or `df2.x.append(df1.A)` ?

Comment: I want to copy over all values in A of df1 into column x of df2

Answer (score 0):

Create the dataframe with the data already in it...

```
dataframeB = pd.DataFrame(dataframeA['A'], columns = ['x'])
```

Then you can add columns in from the other dataframe:

```
dataframeB['y'] = dataframeA['B']
```

Result:

```
  x  y
  1  2 
  1  2
```

Comment: This solution won't work for the actual dataframes I'm working with which are preexisting and much more complex. Is there a way to solve the issue without recreating dataframeB?